# How to call XML-RPC from WSO2 API Manager?

Tags: xml, wso2, wso2-api-manager, xml-rpc, api-gateway

Invoking XML-RPC method from Postman Works good but when i deploy this API in the WSO2 API Gateway it give me an "error decoding RPC".

**Example of XML payload.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
   <methodName>vpop.emailinfo</methodName>
      <params>
         <param>
            <value><string>oussama@test.com</string></value>
         </param>
      </params>
</methodCall>
```

**Example of error response :**

```
<string>error decoding RPC.

no element found at line 1, column 0, byte -1 at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/XML/Parser.pm line 187.
</string>
```

I have to add Content-Length to the header with the value  in Postman to works.but when i add this to API Manager still same error.

Comment: Try configuring the `disable-chunking` mediation policy with the respective API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As mentioned by Athiththan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74112150/how-to-call-xml-rpc-from-wso2-api-manager/75132274#comment132580899_74112150), I tried adding the `disable-chunking` mediation policy with the respective API and it works .